# MS SQL JDBC Connection String for SQL Authentication

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

When attempting to connect to a MS SQL Database using the MS SQL JDBC driver with SQL Authentication, I keep running into issues referencing SSL encryption.

We currently do not use Certificates for data transmission as this is an Internal database... So what is the magical connection string to connect to the database with SQL Authentication?

Currently I am attempting to connect using the following connection string...

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<server:port>;databaseName=<database>;user=<user>;password=<password>;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
```

I have tried adding and removing the different properties without any success.

The current error I am getting is...

> Remote JDBC error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
> The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by
> using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Certificates do
> not conform to algorithm constraints".

Comment: Combining user=;password=;integratedSecurity=true is already wrong, you either have username/password, ie. sql server auth or use integratedsecurity=true which means windows authentication. As for the rest, what happens when you do: encrypt = false? Also, please include your windows and sql server version

Comment: This might be a TLS issue. What version of SQL Server are you using? What does `PRINT @@VERSION;` return?

Comment: using... jdbc:sqlserver://<server:port>;databaseName=<database>;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true;  returns... Remote JDBC error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints". I am using Red Hat to connect to Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU4-GDR) (KB5029185) - 12.0.6449.1 (X64)

Comment: Does the server have `Force Encryption` set to ON? Have you updated Windows Server to the latest version and build? Have you updated JDBC and Java to the latest version?

Comment: You still have `integratedSecurity=true;` if you want to use SQL Authetication that should be *false*.

Comment: I don't have access to the Windows Server, or to tell if Force Encryption is set to ON.  I have tried using sqljdbc_12.2  sqljdbc_4.0  sqljdbc_4.1  sqljdbc_6.2 versions of the Microsoft JDBC driver.  I can connect using jTDS but not with the Microsoft. I want to move away from jTDS as there appears to be some memory leaks.

Comment: try mssqljdbc 9.1.1, i run some sql server 2014 myself on a really old system and that driver works just fine. Also, please post the whole stacktrace and not just the greatest hits